# Connect to localhost

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I created a localhost server and now I want to connect to my localhost except that it asks me for a username that I am not changing so I tried to use the root username and the empty password because I am on wamp and its my wrong username

To try to solve my problem I looked at the wamp configuration files and I went to phpmyadmin but it didn't give me anything

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to login to phpMyAdmin on WAMPServer?

Comment: Yes, but suddenly I uninstalled and reinstalled wamp and it works